# Data format error but value causing the error doesn't seem to exist?

Tags: powerquery

[image]

I cannot share the data I am working with for privacy reasons. Though I will do my best to explain the issue --

I am building a query from a dataset that I know pretty well. There are about 15 date columns -- errors have been removed in the date columns. The rest of the columns contain text data. At the Table.Pivot step, I encounter a data format error -- except the value that seems to be causing the error ("mr2021") doesn't exist in the data. I have explored the data in Excel and R to try to find this value and remove it, but it doesn't seem to exist. I can't figure out how to find what row contains this value that power query is trying to parse as a date value. I've already cleaned the two date columns to ensure that those columns aren't causing the issue. In addition, the columns that I'm pivoting are NOT the date columns. So I really have no clue why PQ is throwing this error... any ideas?

I've tried:

- Converting all columns to type text to try to stop PQ from trying to convert values to dates
- Removing all errors prior to pivoting
- Trimming all values in the dataset

Answer (score 1):

As the very first step, add column, index column to Source. Do this before any other step or column type settings

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"Column1", type date}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

Before the step currently generating the error, add a new step that changes the relevant column to type date. Delete all subsequent steps after that new one. File .. close and load the query. It should return an error for the query (see image). Click on the error link and it will open and show you anything where the type change failed to work, along with row number from the previous step, and the index number from the original data

(Alternatively, filter the data at some point for the item, and see what the index is)

[image]

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I removed my comment pretty much immediately after posting it because I realized it was probably unhelpful. to clarify -- the columns I am pivoting don't seem to be involved because they don't contain any date values or numerical values at all, just string values (and I have a list of the string values used). so it seems the error is coming from one of the other 50 columns in the dataset.

Comment: I'm currently trying reduce my dataset to just the date columns (plus the index column) to then filter for errors and see if the problematic value is in one of the date columns, even though the value doesn't seem to exist

Comment: okay this is so strange -- so I reduced my dataset to just the columns that contain dates. When I filter for errors, I get 280 records that have the value "mr2021" in each cell for each column... like what? So weird. I'm going to try replacing those errors with nulls like I tried to do before and then try re-pivoting my data, but I still don't understand where this weird value is coming from that can't be found in my dataset outside of power query...

Comment: another update. so even when I replace all those error values with "null", I still get the same error that the value "mr2021" cannot be converted to date... so I guess my only option is to just filter out those rows entirely from my dataset?? so strange

Comment: If you have 100% verified that text is not in your original data set (by looking at the data in notepad or some other text based editor) then you are introducing that value somehow via your (unshared) code.  Now that you know which column the mr2021 can appear in, I suggest you delete your code steps one by one until you discover which step is introducing that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to proceed with the table pivot by doing the following:

1. Converting all columns to type = text
2. Replacing all errors with null
3. Removing blank rows

Comment: That does not actually solve your issue; if your code is introducing errors to the data, it might be doing something else as well that you are not seeing, but happy it worked for you

Comment: @horseyride I believe it was the blank cells causing the error but haven't had time to investigate further. I will try to investigate the root problem more. I really appreciate your help and insight and am sorry I irritated you with my initial comment deletion, I totally understand why that would be frustrating and know for the future now to add additional comments for clarification rather than deleting comments